# JQuery DOM manipulation with two input fields when capturing a checked event

Tags: jquery

I have a list and the list is made up of some input fields, one being a text and the other being a checkbox. When the checkbox is checked, I would like JQuery to grab the previous input field and change the color of the font to red.

Is there a way in Jquery to do this?

```
        newListItem = '<li><span class="handle"> :: <input class="listItem" style="color:#1C94C4;" value="' + theValue + '"><input class="addTodaysItem" type="checkbox" style="width:20px;"></span><a class="removeListItem" style="display: none;" href="#"> X </a> </li>';

    var $thisEntry = $(this).find('input:previous');
    if(this.checked){
        $thisEntry.css('color', 'red');
    }
    else {
        $thisEntry.css('color', '#1C94C4');    
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

replace :

```
var $thisEntry = $(this).find('input:previous');
```

with :

```
 var $thisEntry = $(this).prev('input');
```

as there is no `:previous` psuedo selector, and assuming there actually is a scope where `this` is what you think it is.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Where can I find this and other useful Jquery DOM manipulation methods.